# Testing openstack services on devstack

Tags: openstack, devstack

I have successfully installed devstack on my machine and I get the horizon dashboard. Now, I don't know what to do with it?? I am suppsed to test the OpenStack Services. I wonder if I should install swift (The same question for Nova and Glance) or it is already done? If I have to install it, could anyone help me with a good tutorial. Fianlly, Could I install it through the dashboard?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like repeat of this question https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/9707/testing-devstack/

Hope it helps.

Cheers!!

Comment: More explicitly, I want to know what I can do with the horizn dashboard when I get it @koolhead17

Comment: did you had chance to check devstack.org? The url has enough information about everything. :)

Comment: I want to know if it is possible to access for example the swift service through the horizon dashboard.

Comment: Could you explain me how please or would  you give me a link for a tutorial

Comment: please tell me what should i explain to you. The link i provided you tells you about how to install Swift with devstack.

Comment: I mean how to access swift through horizon?

Comment: if you have swift installed and dashboard properly covered you will see the swift tab on sidebar left. from there you can create & do all the swift related operations.

Comment: I have two tabs actually project and admin. Which one is for swift?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4eW78gHfCg  Check the video it shows the dashboard demo. On the project tab in bottom u will see object storage, that is the one for swift.